# Aura Slider - How to change the slider range color from grey to blue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to change the range bar color from grey to blue. Please help

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="val" type="Integer" default="50"/>
    <lightning:slider label="Volume" value="{!v.val}"/>
</aura:component>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXJX2.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
:host {
    --sds-c-slider-track-color-background: orange;
    --sds-c-slider-thumb-color-foreground: black;
}
```

You can see the documentation here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-slider/documentation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).